# Specifying a CGRect of Int on a function header

Tags: swift, swift5, cgrect

CGRect structure can contain  be of Int, Double or CGFloat.

if I create this function header

```
func doSomething(rect:CGRect) {
```

and later send a CGRect of Int or Double values, Xcode will whine that I must send a CGRect of CGFloats.

How do I make Xcode stop whining and accept the CGRect of Int I am sending.

I know I can create a struct containing Int values or convert the values to CGFloat and solve this but I would like to know if there is a way to solve this.

Comment: can't replicate your issue. Can you please elaborate? Do you mean you can not change its properties?

Comment: CGRect `x`, `y`, `width` and  `height` are all read only properties (get) so I don understand what is your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CGRect structure can contain be of Int, Double or CGFloat.

No, it can't.

Though it's possible to initialize a *CGRect structure* with *Int, Double or CGFloat* values, internally all struct members are based on the `CGFloat` type.

Please see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect)